# Should I catch all my exceptions in the global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, logging, exception, global-asax

If I am just logging exception details in my web app, do I really need to put in exception handling logic for each tier? Why not just let them all bubble up the stack trace to the global.asax and log them there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest against using *any* exception handling logic in any layer of your application unless:

- The exception is not a fatal one, meaning that there is some action you can take to recover, or
- The application should continue functioning and the exception should be "ignored." An example: when checking out at an online retailer you are sent a receipt via email. If that fails - but the other order processing stuff succeeds - the user should not be shown an error page. Here, we want the workflow to continue even though there is an exception. Most exceptions do not fall into this category.

Of course, exceptions - whether they are fatal or not or should be "ignored" or not - need to be logged and developers notified. This is best handled through an event handler for the `Application.Error` event. Yes, this can be done in `Global.asax`, but I think it's cleaner to use an HTTP Module-based approach, either [Health Monitoring](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031407-1.aspx) or [ELMAH](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx).

I've written an article on this topic that I'd like to recommend to you - [Exception Handling Advice for ASP.NET Web Applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134127/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081209-1.aspx). Here is the article in summary:

> My advice for handling exceptions in an ASP.NET application can be boiled down to the following guidelines:
>
> (a) Create and use a meaningful custom error page.
>
> (b) In general, do not catch exceptions. Let them bubble up to the ASP.NET runtime. Some cases where catching an exception makes sense include:
>
> - When there is a plausible way to recover from the exception by performing some alternative logic,
> - When a peripheral part of the application's workflow throws and exception and that exception should not derail the entire application, and
> - When you need to include additional information with the exception by throwing a new exception that has the original exception as its inner exception.
>
> (c) Log all exceptions to some persistent store and use email (or some other medium) to notify developers when an exception occurs in production. Consider using ELMAH or ASP.NET's built-in Health Monitoring system to facilitate this process.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions should bubble up to whatever layer can handle them in a meaningful way, being aware of the [Single Responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29). For instance, your data layer should not be invested in logging.

The Application.Error event is a good place for catch-all error handling: that is, unexpected and/or fatal errors that require no special treatment beyond logging/alerting and redirecting to an error page.

Answer (score 2):

If your web app makes use of the Microsoft AJAX extensions and partial postbacks, you'll need to handle exceptions in at least two places:

1. Global.asax
2. Your ScriptManager's OnAsyncPostBackError handler

For further information on OnAsyncPostBackError, check out:

http://msforge.net/blogs/janko/archive/2008/02/13/handling-exceptions-in-asp-net-ajax.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.onasyncpostbackerror.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I say that on global try to catch the error that you miss on the logic steps of your program and redirect them on an "error page", or a "not found page".

All other errors not necessary show the error on the user, and not need to send it to an error page.

For example, in page with 2 or more, different modules, if the one throw an error, just hide it, and show the rest. Similar try to catch errors when they happens and handle them the best non visual way to the user if this is possible, log them and correct them later.

Now this error that happens only on one module, you can see it on your log and correct it, but until you do that, user see something on your page and not a full error page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I do is do a try...catch in the code, but instead of logging on the catch what I do is pass it on with a message stating where the error came from, etc.  Then I use Elmah to catch all of the errors and log them.

That way you only have to deal with the logging in one area and satisfy the Single Responsiblity Principle, but you have more information available for debugging purposes.  It can also be helpful when you get that data error that only seems to occur with 1 out of 500 users.

Comment: Does the exception's stack trace not provide enough information as to where the error is originating?

Comment: Your right, that should be all I need for it.  What I'm doing is a bit overkill.